# Set default printer according to IP

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, printing, sh

**Setup:**

I use my notebook in two locations. At each location, the computer receives an IP address via DHCP. This IP address depends on the location, but is constant for each location over time. Furthermore, at each location there is a printer.

**Task:**

I configured both printers and would like to set the default printer according to the IP. To this purpose, I wrote a script and put it under `/etc/network/if-up.d/set-default-printer`, using `lpoptions -d` to actually set the default printer.

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/sh

ip_A="1.1.1.1"
ip_B="2.2.2.2"

pr_A="Printer-A"
pr_B="Printer-B"


ip=$(hostname -I | cut -d " " -f 1)

if [ $ip = $ip_A ]; then 
    lpoptions -d $pr_A
    touch /home/user/A
fi

if [ $ip = $ip_B ]; then 
    lpoptions -d $pr_B
    touch /home/user/B
fi
```

**Problem:**

Unfortunately, the default printer is not changed by the script (can be checked via `lpoptions` without further arguments).

**Further diagnostics:**

1. The script works when I either paste the content to or just call it from the command line.
2. The script is executed by the `if-up`-mechanism, which is verified by the creation of files `/home/user/(A|B)`.
3. In particular, following from 1 or 2, the script file itself is executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `lpoptions` needs to be executed as the local user. Hence, replacing

```
lpoptions -d $pr
```

by

```
sudo -H -u user lpoptions -d $pr
```

for both printers `$pr` solves the problem.

Assuming, `user` is your user name, the complete script `/etc/network/if-up.d/set-default-printer` is now:

```
#!/bin/sh

ip_A="1.1.1.1"
ip_B="2.2.2.2"

pr_A="Printer-A"
pr_B="Printer-B"


ip=$(hostname -I | cut -d " " -f 1)

if [ $ip = $ip_A ]; then 
    sudo -H -u user lpoptions -d $pr_A
fi

if [ $ip = $ip_B ]; then 
    sudo -H -u user lpoptions -d $pr_B
fi
```